# Retraction by deformation

Tags: morse-theory

in Theorem 3.1 in the book Morse theory by Milnor , in the end of the proof they say that :
[image]

$r_t$ is a deformation retract ?

how to prove this ?

please

thank you

Answer (score 0):

A deformation retract is, by definition, a homotopy between a retraction and the identity map. This is exactly what we have here: the homotopy is given by

$$H:M^b \times [0,1] \rightarrow M^b, H(q,t) = r_t(q).$$

Comment: ok, but please why $r_1$ is a retraction from $M^b$ to $M^a$ ?

Comment: A retraction means that $r_1$ is continuous and acts as the identity on $M^a$. Continuity is clear as we are gluing two continuous maps together. If $q \in M^a$, then by definition we have $f(q) \leq a$, so that $r_1(q) = q$.

Comment: and where $\varphi_{t(a-f(q))}$ is used ?

Comment: It's used to see that $H$ is indeed an homotopy.

Comment: H muste verify that $H(q,0)=q$ for $q \in M^b$ ...1 ; $H(q,1)\in M^a$ for $q \in M^b$...2 ;$H(q,t)=q , \forall q \in M^a, \forall t\in [0,1]$...3  , for 1 that'ok , for 2 :let $q\in M^b$, $r_1(q)=\varphi_{a-f(q)}$ why it is in $M^a$ ?? please

Comment: I explained that in my first comment.

Comment: i don't see in your comment that $\varphi_{a-f(q)} \in M^a$ !

Comment: i must prove that $f\varphi_{a-f(q)} (q)\leq a $?

Comment: we have that when $q\in M^a$ $r_t(q)=q$ for all t ,but what is the use of $\varphi_{a-f(q)}$ ? please